# Time out error for Email server, i am trying to send and email from my application but its not working

Tags: vb.net

i made an application where i need to send some of information to my self i am clueless what to do so i decided it to send through email which also not working giving timeout error
here is the code

`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    Dim s As New SmtpClient
    s.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    s.Port = 465
    s.EnableSsl = True
    s.Timeout = 55000
    s.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    s.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("********@gmail.com", "*************")
    Dim m As New MailMessage
    m.To.Add("******@gmail.com")
    m.From = New MailAddress("*******@gmail.com")
    m.Body = "Test Message"
    m.Subject = "Test Subject"
    s.Send(m)
    MsgBox("done")
    Exit Sub
End sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use port 587 for sending e-mails via a .NET application. **Ensure that the sender's Gmail account has access to "Less secured app" permission as shown:**

[image: Less secure app access system]

See if it works, if doesn't, then try the following code and don't forget to customize it with your sufficient information:

```
Dim SmtpCRequest As New SmtpClient
Dim MailProperty As New MailMessage()

With SmtpCRequest
    .UseDefaultCredentials = False
    .Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(<username>, <password>)
    .Port = 587
    .EnableSsl = True
    .Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
End With

With MailProperty
    .From = New MailAddress(New TripleDES("TOKEN").DecryptData(Cred(0)))
    .To.Add("******@gmail.com")
    .Subject = "Your Subject"
    .IsBodyHtml = False
    .Body = "Email Body is here."
End With

SmtpCRequest.Send(MailProperty)
MailProperty.Dispose()
```